# How to refer to a method?

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm trying to create a router for a web application (yes, I know solutions already exist).

Thus far I've got this:

```
class Route
{
    public static RegexOptions DefaultOptions = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase;

    Regex regex;
    Type controller;
    MethodInfo action;

    public Route(string pattern, Type controller)
    {
        this.regex = new Regex(string.Format("^(?:{0})$", pattern), DefaultOptions);
        this.controller = controller;
    }
}
```

And this:

```
    Route[] routes = {
        new Route(@"/user:(?<id>\d+)", typeof(UserController))
    };
```

When the URL matches that regex, it should call the method `action` in class `controller`. I'm thinking `typeof()` is the only way I can pass the class around, but how about the method?

I think `MethodInfo` is the object I want, because with that I should be able to invoke it, but from an API perspective, what should the 3rd argument to `Route` constructor be, and how should we call it?

I prefer a strongly-typed solution rather than some string shenanigans.

Comment: What should the action method be called?

Comment: @Martinho: Huh? "action" is fine. My question is about syntax. Ideally I'd just write `new Route("pattern", UserController.Method)` but C# doesn't support such syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the non-existent [`infoof` operator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/21/in-foof-we-trust-a-dialogue.aspx).

Unfortunately, it doesn't exist.

The simplest answer is to take a string.
Alternatively, you can take an [expression tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx).
The disadvantage to taking an expression tree is that your caller must pass all parameters.
You could work that into your framework (by taking an `Expression<Func<parameters, ResultType>>`), and perhaps even compile the expression tree to call the actions.  (which will result in much faster calls than reflection)

Comment: That `infoof` article mentions a few problems I didn't really think about... perhaps it is better and simpler to go with strings after all, even if I don't get the compile-time type safety.

Comment: To deal with the ambiguities, however, I'd have it return `MethodInfo[]` with all possible matches :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a way to refer to a instance method in c sharp without an instance. Unless you want the user of the API to define a MethodInfo object to pass in, string name may be the best way.

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Route r = new Route("pattern", typeof(UserController), "Action");
    }
}

public class Route
{
    public Route(string pattern, Type type, string methodName)
    {
        object objectToUse = Activator.CreateInstance(type, null);
        MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod(methodName);
        string[] args = new string[1];
        args[0] = "hello world";
        method.Invoke(objectToUse, args);
    }
}

public class UserController
{
    public void Action(string message)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait...`new Callback<UserController>(Action)`, if `Action` is an instance method in UserController... how does this even compile?

Comment: @Ralph: [Delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171(VS.80%29.aspx) like `Callback` represent methods, as in "pieces of code that can be run". MethodInfo represents a method as in "a member with a name and a signature".

Comment: I'm surprised nobody said it sooner.. Nobody even mentioned delegates!

Comment: Ohhh..you initialized an instance of user beforehand. That makes more sense now :) Is there a way to do it without constructing a userController first though?

Comment: @Ralph only if Action is a static method in UserController, then you can get rid of the object and pass UserController.Action to InitRoute

Comment: @Ralph if you just want to call a static method in UserController, the solution is actually much much simpler, I can update my example if you want

Comment: @Ralph sorry for the many comments, but I just took out the generics, and it works fine for both static and non-static methods. Take a look at the example again

Comment: @Samuel: It's supposed to be an instance method, but the class is only supposed to be initialized once a match is found, the API user shouldn't have to manually initialize it before specifying the routes. I have to give some thought to this... *maybe* static method will do...

Comment: Regardless though, there's another hitch, and this is the reason I wanted to use MethodInfo in the first place. You're assuming the Action doesn't take any parameters... it does. Those are hidden in the regex, using `(?<id>\d+)` in the regex means that whatever it captures will be passed to the "id" parameter and automatically type-casted... I'll need to do a lot of reflection on the method.

Comment: @Ralph Well the only way I could do all you ask is by using a string method name.. Sorry pal!

Comment: @Samuel: Haha, yes, I think I reached the same conclusion :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create something like this:

```
MethodInfo GetMethodInfo(LambdaExpression expression)
{
    var call = expression.Body as MethodCallExpression;
    if(call == null) throw new ArgumentException("Must be a method call","expression");
    return call.Method;
}

MethodInfo GetMethodInfo<T>(Expression<Action<T>> expression)
{
    return GetMethodInfo(expression);
}

MethodInfo GetMethodInfo<T, TResult>(Expression<Func<T, TResult>> expression)
{
    return GetMethodInfo(expression);
}
```

And use it like this:

```
MethodInfo action = GetMethodInfo((UserController c) => c.ActionMethod());
// or
MethodInfo action = GetMethodInfo((UserController c) =>
                                        c.ActionMethodWithParams(default(int)));
```

This won't call the method immediately because it is an expression tree, i.e., a syntactic tree representing the method call.

Comment: This assumes controller methods take no parameters. Otherwise, passing `null` and `default()` are necessary

Comment: Ah! A few people mentioned these "expression trees" but no one provided a code example.. I think I see how this works now. Thank you :)

Comment: @statenjason: No it doesn't assume anything about controller actions (for a couple minutes it assumed a return value, but never anything about parameters). But yes, you have to pass dummy values. I prefer default because it helps picking between overloads.